# Потоки в цикле создаются по несколько раз

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, ранее создавал тему по проблеме, но тогда я не знал что конкретно работает не так.
На данный момент выяснил в чем проблема, потоки в методе создаются по несколько раз с одинаковыми параметрами.

```
for (int t = 0; t <= tCount - 1; t++)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        int id = t;
        bool DoMain = true;
        int c = int.Parse(arr.GetValue(0, t - 1).ToString()), c_ = int.Parse(arr.GetValue(1, t - 1).ToString());
        string fw = null, model = null, type = null, link = null;
        int size = 0;
        int a_thread = a, b_thread = b;
        Task<bool> tryget = null;
        int f = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("CREATE THREAD " + id + " WITH PARAMS : C = " + c + " C_ = " + c_);

        while (DoMain)
        {
            try
            {
                iterCount.Invoke(new Action(() => { iterCount.Text = string.Format("Количество итераций : {0}", ++iCount); }));
            }
            catch { Console.WriteLine("ERROR ON 154"); }

            {
                link = string.Format("http://update.hicloud.com:8180/TDS/data/files/p3/s15/G{0}/g{1}/v{2}/f{3}/full/changelog.xml", a_thread, b_thread, c, f);
                //Console.WriteLine("THREAD " + id + " LINK " + link);
                tryget = TryGetV3(link);
                tryget.Wait();
                if (tryget.Result)
                {
                    fw = xmlGetModel(link);
                    size = xmlGetSize(link);

                    //============================Вносим данные в форму============================
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (string s in readModels)
                        {
                            if (fw.Contains(s))
                            {
                                model = s;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (size > 1500000000) { type = "FULL"; } else { type = "OTA"; }
                        dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => { dataGridView1.Rows.Add(model, fw, type, link, "Download", a_thread, b_thread, c, f, id); }));
                        firmwareCount.Invoke(new Action(() => { firmwareCount.Text = string.Format("Найдено прошивок : {0}", dataGridView1.Rows.Count); }));
                    }
                    catch { Console.WriteLine("ERROR ON 188"); }

                }
                link = null;
            }

            try
            {
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, string.Format(@"{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch { }

            //FOR V LOOP
            ++c;
            if (c < c_)
                DoMain = true;
            else
                DoMain = false;

            fw = null; model = null; type = null; link = null; size = 0; tryget = null;
        }
    }){IsBackground = true}.Start();
}
```

Вывод строчки `Console.WriteLine("CREATE THREAD " + id + " WITH PARAMS : C = " + c + " C_ = " + c_);`

```
CREATE THREAD 7 WITH PARAMS : C = 47306 C_ = 47356
CREATE THREAD 7 WITH PARAMS : C = 47306 C_ = 47356
CREATE THREAD 7 WITH PARAMS : C = 47306 C_ = 47356
CREATE THREAD 7 WITH PARAMS : C = 47306 C_ = 47356
CREATE THREAD 7 WITH PARAMS : C = 47306 C_ = 47356
CREATE THREAD 8 WITH PARAMS : C = 47357 C_ = 47407
CREATE THREAD 8 WITH PARAMS : C = 47357 C_ = 47407
CREATE THREAD 8 WITH PARAMS : C = 47357 C_ = 47407
CREATE THREAD 11 WITH PARAMS : C = 47510 C_ = 47560
CREATE THREAD 11 WITH PARAMS : C = 47510 C_ = 47560
CREATE THREAD 11 WITH PARAMS : C = 47510 C_ = 47560
```

Т.е. создается несколько одинаковых потоков, с одинаковыми параметрами, почему так происходит? Как с этим можно бороться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас тут целая куча плохо читаемого кода, но рискну предположить, что проблема в захвате переменной цикла лямбда-функцией. Попробуйте написать так:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= tCount - 1; counter++)
{
    int t = counter;
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        .......
    });
}
```

Пару слов о том, что это такое. Дело в том, что любая лямбда-функция в C# неявно преобразуется компилятором в класс, с методом, представляющим собой тело лямбда-функции. При этом, если лямбда захватывает какие-то внешние переменные, то есть в её теле используются переменные из внешнего по отношению к лямбде кода (в вашем случае это параметр t цикла for и еще ряд других переменных), то в этом закулисном классе они становятся полями. Соответственно, до тех пор, пока лямбда не завершит свою работу, захваченные переменные будут жить (даже если внешний метод уже завершён). В случае со счётчиками циклов (в вашем случае это счётчик цикла, имеющий тип int) происходит вот что: захваченный счётчик тоже становится членом этого "невидимого" класса, и с каждой новой итерацией передаётся в лямбду уже не по значению, а по ссылке. Цикл очень быстро выполняется, проинкрементировав значение счётчика и создав энное количество потоков, тогда как сами потоки не успевают выполниться, и все они (или почти все) используют последнее значение счётчика, так как берут его из захваченной переменной.

Это вполне естественное поведение, однако оно совершенно неочевидно. Поэтому в C# 5 оно было исправлено. Однако если вы используете более раннюю версию языка, то нужно учитывать эту особенность (о которой, кстати, любезно подсказывает Resharper). Вот [хорошая статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/141270/) на эту тему. Впрочем, её уже порекомендовали в комментариях.

Comment: спасибо огромное, это действительно помогло

Comment: Дополню ответ ссылкой, полезно ознакомиться: https://habrahabr.ru/post/141270/