# Выход за пределы массива во время инициализации Task'ов

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы, asp.net-core, task

Имеется приблизительно такой код:

```
public async Task MainThread()
{
    // Заранее неизвестно, сколько будет создано списков и сколько в каждом списке элментов
    List<List<ImportantData>> manyImportantDatas = new List<List<ImportantData>>();

    // Наполнение списка

    // К примеру, выходит следующий результат:
    // manyImportantDatas[0].Count == 2
    // manyImportantDatas[1].Count == 1

    Task[] taskList = new Task[manyImportantDatas.Count]; // В пределах примера Task[2]
    for (int i = 0; i < manyImportantDatas.Count; i++)
    {
        taskArray[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // Строка ниже внезапно вызывает исключение:
            // Index was out of range
            List<Parameters> parametersList = new List<Parameters>(manyImportantDatas[i].Count);
            foreach (var importantData in manyImportantDatas[i])
            {
                parametersList[i] = new Parameters()
                {
                    // Заполнение параметров
                }
            }
            await CallOtherAPI(parametersList: parametersList);
        });
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
}
```

Расставив BreakPoint'ы я внезапно увидел, что у меня i == 2. Тогда я прошёлся пошагово по всем строкам, начиная с объявления цикла. Получилась следующая картина:
`taskArray[i] = Task.Run(async () =>` - i == 0,
`List<Parameters> parametersList = new List` - i == 1
При повторении цикла (а я не понимаю даже почему он повторился, ибо i уже == 1), повторилась та же ситуация, что на строке `taskArray[i] = Task.Run(async () =>` i == 1, а уже на следующей i == 2. Соответственно, "Index was out of range".

Что я сделал неправильно, почему у меня так странно наращивается i?

**UPD:** Пару раз мне удавалось успеть дойти до `Task.WaitAll(taskArray);`

Comment: типичная проблема с захватом переменной. Поставьте в начале вашего цикла `var index = i;` и используйте дальше только `index` переменную.

Comment: @tym32167 Из-за чего такое происходит?

Comment: вы создаете Таск `Task.Run(()=>{и тут используете переменную i})`, но таск стартует не сразу - ему надо время, чтобы стартануть. К моменту когда он стартанет, ваша переменная i уже дошла до конца цикла, а вы захватили ссылку на неё, вот у вас внутри таска они и имеет значение 2

Comment: Когда вы пишете `var index = i;` , то вы копируете значение переменной i в index, и после я вам посоветовал захватывать index, так как переменная index в цикое не меняется, и к моменту старта вашего таска они будет держать всё ещё то значение, которое в неё было скопировано.

Comment: @tym32167 Как ответ продублируете комментарий?

Comment: да я сйечас дубликат найду, подобная прблема часто случается

Comment: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011408/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009090/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/856702/179763), [четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677965/179763), [пять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560524/179763)